# Apache is crashing and auto restarting on digitalocean

Tags: server, apache2

I recently requested a change to my root password which was successful and I am able to use it on the console. However, my IP address stopped working. Both visiting my domain and SSH are responding with a connection timed out error.

It was working fine until my root password changed and the server was restarted.

I checked the error log using this command:

```
tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

And this is what i got:

```
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 994] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [core:notice] [pid 994] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 981] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 970] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020 [core:notice] [pid 970] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 903] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 903] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [core:notice] [pid 994] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 994] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 970] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.2g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 20 00:47:06.157921 2020] [core:notice] [pid 990] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Notice the `SIGTERM, shutting down`? I think Apache is crashing and the service is auto-restarting.

At first I thought it was as a result of low memory usage then I checked with this command `free -mh`

here are the results. My Ram is enough:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1.9G        259M        1.4G         612K        258M        1.6G
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

Firewall is inactive so nothing is blocking port 80

```
sudo ufw status
Status: Inactive
```

I also run this command to see what's being listened on

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P

COMMAND    PID           USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd      812           root    3u  IPv4  18468      0t0  TCP  localhost:53 (LISTEN)
sshd      812           root    4u  IPv6  18468      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
mysqld      899           mysql    29u  IPv4  19368      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
master      1089           root    13u  IPv4  19478      0t0  TCP *:25 (LISTEN)
master      1089           root    14u  IPv6  19479      0t0  TCP *:25 (LISTEN)
```

Could I be my Apache configurations?
here is what is being listened to on my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`

```
grep "Listen" /etc/apache2/*.conf

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 0.0.0.0

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 433
etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 433
```

I can't even restart apache it doesn't let me

```
service apache2 restart

Job for apache2.service failed because the control proccess exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

On running that command I got this:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
         apache-system.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-01-20 12:16:35 UTC; 4min 9s
Process: 1616 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

Is this normal? Please help

Comment: should it not be port 443 rather than 433?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen yes you are right.

Comment: i just changed it to 433 but the error is still showing

Comment: You mean 443 and check your logs again.

Comment: running apache2ctl configtest warned about syntax error on the ports.conf file. I fixed it from this

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 0.0.0.0

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 433
etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 433

to this

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 80

etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 443
etc/apache2/ports.conf: Listen 443

Comment: but my server is still down

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i think that did something because i got a new error on the logs
now it's saying 
apache2: could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name using 127.0.0.1. Set the "ServerName" directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: No you didn't there's a particular file it's looking for with the FQDN and it's not created by default ignore that for now is the server running?

Comment: no it says "Unable to resolve host [ubuntu]" on every request